# How to get the current User from IHttpContextAccessor (asp.net core 3)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been trying to get the User (`ClaimsPrincipal` or `IPrincipal`) from the current `HttpContext`.

It is available from controllers via the .User property.

However, using DI in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, the user info is never populated.

My startup looks like:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication5.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddTransient<System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal>(o =>
            {
                var context = o.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext;
                return context?.User;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The code in question:

```c#
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddTransient<System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal>(o =>
            {
                var context = o.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext;
                return context?.User;
            });
```

This seems to be what other posters on SO have suggested, but it is never populated?

Specifically, it is the Name property (and Claims) I am interested in but is never set.

edit: I'm specifically trying to pass the user info to my IdentityContext for auditing. However, the user (`IPrincipal`) is never populated like it is automatically on Controllers.

Comment: When you’re trying to use it, are you in the context of a currently executing controller action that has an `[Authorize]` or similar attribute on it (or its controller)?

Comment: No. In this case I am testing on the default Home/index and there is no [Authorize]

Comment: You won’t have a meaningful `User` object unless something is causing it to run the authentication part of the pipeline (like an attribute for authorisation). Also, injecting an `IPrincipal` is likely to cause issues, as parts of the pipeline that might be required to establish its value will not have run yet, at the point at which the controller factory creates the controller. Try just use `HttpContext.User` directly in your controller code instead.

Comment: Except, ultimately I do not intend accessing from controller. Rather services and my dbcontext, hence the need for DI.

Comment: That should be fine, but I would rather inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into those instead, and use it to get the `User` when needed.

Comment: I will try that and update asap

Comment: @sellotape same result. Passed IHttpContextAccessor to my context. The resulting `.User.Identity.*` still empty.

Comment: What about when calling a method with an `[Authorize]` attribute (as above)?  The default behaviour for anonymous requests is that the authentication part of the pipeline is not invoked, so there is no user.

Comment: Tried that also (threw an [authorize] on the Home/Index action). Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this.
I use this with jwt, but it should be similar.

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value
```